# How to add certificates into iOS app Sandbox

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, certificate

I want to add certificates into my iOS app project to communicate with a server.

1. Could you tell me how to add CAs into iOS app Sandbox? I added a resource directory which includes CAs in Xcode. But I'm not sure this is a right way....
2. Is there any way that I can access to the Sandbox to change them without using Xcode? I want to know how to update CAs after releasing the app.

[Environment]

- Xcode 12.4
- Language: Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

Keeping Push Certificates in Bundle won't work.
You need to have the certificates, first in your keychain and when you archive the  build make sure you use these certificates for signing.

Also, you need to send a copy of your push certificate either .p12 or .p8 to the backend developer for communication with APNs.

Follow the link for steps to generate Certificate:

https://medium.com/zero-equals-false/generate-apns-certificate-for-ios-push-notifications-85e4a917d522